# I can't resolve s3 dns from time-to-time

Tags: dns, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm using the .net SDK to talk to S3, but too often I get the following exception:

```
The remote name could not be resolved: 's3.amazonaws.com'
```

I'm using the two standard OpenDNS DNS servers, and falling-back to my ISP's DNS (verizon fios).  Something is up here.  When I ping s3.amazonaws.com the requests time out.  Thoughts on what might be going wrong or other diagnostics I can run?

Comment: Can you try other websites and Google's DNS?

Comment: Other websites resolve just fine.  I could try Google DNS and see if it helps...but I thought OpenDNS was supposed to be rock solid

Comment: @SFun28 Everything might fail, but you mention having a fallback DNS. Having them both fail is rather unlikely. Google's DNS could be another good fallback though, at least to debug (yes I'm aware the topic is a year old, but this might be useful for other readers).

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? It's 4 years later but I am getting the exact same error from time to time on my S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Amazon disallow ping requests (at least to the S3 service).

Further reading can be found here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109#11